# Solution for creating a firewall filter layer (c/c++) on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, firewall, wdk, filter-driver

I'm developing an app for filtering network connections from clients to my server (deny or allow to connect to my server).
I'm researching and found some resources like Windows Firewall API.
But I don't know if it's necessary for me or not.
What's the best API or solution to resolve it?
Thank so much.

regards,

Comment: What are you trying to filter? If they are connecting to your server then surely that's the place to deny/allow rather than being very invasive with a network filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an already-developed and proven app in the first place? If you really want to develop a filtering layer then what you need is a [Filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and more specifically [NDIS filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565492.aspx) . A sample solution can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570732.aspx). But unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing and what you want to achieve I'd strongly suggest that you stick to an off-the-shelf solution - any firewall will be decent, or even a linux machine in front of your server with appropriate iptables rules.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working in a windows operating system. You would have to make use of Windows Filtering Platform as seen in  the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510.aspx

Drivers like TDS,LSP, and NDIS are all deprecated.

The programming language is C++. In my experience, it was  a desktop application with the GUI in WxWidget and writing the filtering network connections hooks into the user mode.

There are two Filtering Layer Identifiers (Run-time Filtering Layer Identifiers and Management Filtering Layer Identifiers ), i made  used  of the earlier being that its more effective.

Should you need more assistance let me know.